# Measure theory problem concerning convergence of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a measure space. Let $S_j$, $j \in \mathbb N$ be an increasing sequence of $\sigma$-algebras on $X$ such that $S := \bigcup_{j \geq 0} S_j$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. For every $j$, let $\mu_j$ be a probability measure on $S_j$.

Let $f_{ij}$ $(i, j \in \mathbb N)$ be a double indexed sequence of functions such that that for every $j$, $f_{ij}$ converges $\mu_j$-a.e. to a $S_j$ measurable function $f_j$.

Suppose there exists some probability measure $\mu$ on $S$ such that $f_j$ converges $\mu$-a.e. to a function $f$.

Suppose further that:

- the restriction of $\mu$ to $S_j$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu_j$ for every $j$
- $f_{ij}, f_j, f$ are $\mu$-integrable, and $f_{ij}$ is $\mu_j$-integrable for every $i, j$
- $\int f_{ij} \, d \mu_j \to \int f_j \, d \mu_j$ for every $j$
- $\int f_j \, d \mu \to \int f \, d \mu$

Is it true that there exists a increasing function $b: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $\int f_{n, b(n)} \, d \mu$ converges to $\int f \, d \mu$?

Comment: $S := \cup_{j \geq 0} S_j$ is not necessarily a sigma algebra. So, what do you then mean by $\mu$ and $\int f\,d\mu$?

Comment: Ah let me modify this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Iosif's comment: the family $\sum_j S_j$ virtually never is a $\sigma$-algebra.

But this does not matter: even if $S = S_j$ for all $j$, the claim is clearly false without further restrictions. Indeed, consider $[-1,1]$ with the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra $S = S_j$, and
$$
\begin{gathered}
 \mu(dx) = \tfrac{1}{2} (1 + x) dx , & \mu_j(dx) = \tfrac{1}{2} dx , \\
 f(x) = f_j(x) = 0 , & f_{ij}(x) = 2 i x^{2 i - 1} .
\end{gathered}
$$
Then:
$$
\begin{gathered}
 \lim_{i \to \infty} f_{ij}(x) = f_j(x) \text{ except when $x = \pm 1$,} \\
 f_j(x) = f(x) \text{ for all $x$,} \\
 \int f_{ij}(x) \mu_j(dx) = 0 = \int f_j(x) \mu_j(dx) , \\
 \int f_j(x) \mu(dx) = 0 = \int f(x) \mu(dx) ,
\end{gathered}
$$
but neither of:
$$
\begin{gathered}
 \int f_{i,j(i)}(x) \mu(dx) = \frac{2 i}{2 i + 1} \, , \\
 \int f_{i(j),j}(x) \mu(dx) = \frac{2 i(j)}{2 i(j) + 1}
\end{gathered}
$$
can converge to $0 = \int f(x) \mu(dx)$.

Comment: You beat me to it.  The strategy is: take any example of strict inequality in Fatou's lemma, and you are practically done.